# print max(str(i),''+(i%3==0)*'Fizz'+(i%5==0)*'Buzz')

Tags: python, max

I am struggling to understand how the following lines of code produce the output which they do, please could someone explain this to me?

I am not trying to solve the question or figure out how to produce the required output. I am just trying to understand how this solution which someone else provided works.

```
for i in range(1,101):
    print max(str(i),''+(i%3==0)*'Fizz'+(i%5==0)*'Buzz')
```

The expected output is to print each number from 1 to 100 on a new line, but to print Fizz when the number is a multiple of 3 or print Buzz when the number is a multiple of 5, or print FizzBuzz when the output is a multiple of both 3 and 5

Answer (score 0):

```
max('18', 'Fizz')
# => 'Fizz'
max('19', '')
# => '19'
```

Strings are compared lexicographically, according to the Unicode order of each character. Since numerals `0` to `9` are all earlier in Unicode order than capital letters `F` and `B`, then it follows that e.g. `'18' > 'Fizz'` is `False`. However, the empty string comes first, by definition of lexicographical ordering; so `'19' > ''` is `True`. So whenever we have a `'Fizz'`, a `'Buzz'` or a `'FizzBuzz'`, that's the string that `max` picks; if we don't, and have an empty string, then we get `str(i)` out of `max`.

```
int(True)
# => 1
int(False)
# => 0
18 % 3 == 0
# => True
19 % 3 == 0
# => False
'' + 1 * 'Fizz' + 1 * 'Buzz'
# => 'FizzBuzz'
'' + 0 * 'Fizz' + 0 * 'Buzz'
# => ''
```

How do we even get a `'Fizz'`, a `'Buzz'` or a `'FizzBuzz'` in the first place? `i % 3 == 0` is `True` for numbers cleanly divisible by 3. `True` in Python, if coerced to a number, is `1`. `'Fizz' * 1` gives one repetition of `'Fizz'` (`'Fizz' * 3` would produce `FizzFizzFizz`). On the other hand, for numbers not cleanly divisible by 3, `False` is coerced to `0`; and zero times `'Fizz'` is an empty string. If we have a number that is cleanly divisible by both `3` and `5`, we get `'' + 'Fizz' + 'Buzz'` for the string.